# SqlConnectionStringBuilder - String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: c#, .net

I am attempting to pass in a connection string to an SqlConnectionStringBuilder object, but I get the error: "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean", at runtime.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLClientProj
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string cstr = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=IIPS;Initial Catalog=Autos";

      SqlConnectionStringBuilder cbuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cstr);

      ...
```

As far as I know, cstr is a string, so why SqlConnectionStringBuilder is complaining about expecting a boolean when it doesn't have a constructor which accepts such a type is beyond my understanding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Integrated Security=IIPS
```

needs to be

```
Integrated Security=true
```

'IIPS' is not a boolean (true/false)

In a nutshell, the connection string is made up of property-value pairs,and the "Integrated Security" property specified in your string is expected to be true or false.

Look down at the "Integrated Security" section on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help. Was just a typo though, not a misunderstanding of connection string. I overlooked it because I didn't think that the error would arise at that point in the execution.

Answer (score 2):

The token you are looking for is `SSPI`, not `IIPS`[sic]. Then, of course, you could, as others said, simply use `true` (or `false`).

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but should

```
Integrated Security=IIPS
```

be

```
Integrated Security=True
```